Header - Page number and text does not fit
i am a bit confused how to change my headers so that it fits. I would like to have a header where on odd numbered pages the page numer is on the right and the chapter (not section) name is on the left and even numered pages the other way around. I used the following code but did only manage to move the page numer by using %KernXXem - and this doesnt suit for every chapter name. Further more the chapter number just doesnt appear. I would be super happy if someone could help me, as i am still learning how to use latex. Thank you so much in advance! :

\PassOptionsToPackage{headsepline, automark}{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}     % Kapielname u.ä. nicht kursiv in Kopfzeile
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.4pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}

   
    \RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % provides headers and footers (KOMA Script)
     \clearpairofpagestyles
  




    
    \let\MakeMarkcase\spacedlowsmallcaps
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@nochapters}}%
        {\relax}%
        {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}} 
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markrboth{\textsc{\thechapter}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}\hline}
   \automark[chapter]{chapter}
   {\textsc{\thechapter}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}\hline}}
    %links
    \lehead{\mbox{\hfil{\small\pagemark\kern25em}\headmark\hfil}}
        %rechts
    \rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\small\headmark\kern25em\pagemark}}}
  
  \ofoot[\small\pagemark]{}% only for plain.scrheadings page style (first page of a chapter)



    
    \renewcommand{\headfont}{\small}
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\fixBothHeadlines}[2]{} % <--- ToDo
         \def\toc@heading{%
            \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@nochapters}}%
            {\chapter*{\contentsname}}%chapters
            \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}} 


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

BTW: It seems, your conditional is completely useless, because your are redefining \chaptermark unconditional after it again. Also it seems, there are errors in the code, like \markrboth instead of \markboth. You should correct them. And to change the formatting of the chapter number, I would usually suggest to use \chaptermarkformat. But currently I cannot test your code. I also do not understand, why you are using \kern. Also \hfil inside a \mbox does not really my sense. You would need at least a \makebox with width argument.

I am trying to insert the whole code :

Please don't! Always show only the needed code: → I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?

Chapter with number on the left of the page header and page number on the right of the page header can be done using:
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}

To add a horizontal line below the header, just add option headsepline and maybe option plainheadsepline.
To additional change the case of the marks, you can indeed redefine \MakeMarkcase. It seems you are looking for something like:
\usepackage{microtype}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\textls[80]{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\MakeMarkcase\spacedlowsmallcaps}

But to change the font only, you can indeed use \setkomafont{…}{…} or \addtokomafont{…}{…}, like:
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}

Note: \normalfont is already the base, so I've not added it here.
Altogether, it seems you are looking for something like:
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\textls[80]{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\MakeMarkcase\spacedlowsmallcaps}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


If you also want the header on chapter start pages, you need a class (like the KOMA-Script classes), that support this, e.g., add
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}

to the document preamble of the example above to get:

instead of the page number only on the chapter starting page.
See ”Headers and Footers with scrlayer-scrpage” in the KOMA-Script manuals and also “How to change the head and foot of the page” in the KOMA-Script wiki for more information about using scrlayer-scrpage. See also the scrlayer-scrpage tag here. There are already several questions and answers about this.
